# VBA Macro does not run when pressing run

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Msg As String

    With Sheets("data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        For Each R In Sheets("Coverage Data").Range("A2:AD2")

            Set C = .Rows(1).Find(R.Value, , , xlWhole, , 0)
            If Not C Is Nothing Then
                .Columns(C.Column).Copy R
            Else
                Msg = vllf & R.Value
            End If
        Next

        Application.CutCopyMode = False     
    End With

    If Len(Msg) Then MsgBox "Done" & Msg
End Sub
```

When clicking run on the following code. nothing happens. Please help what is wrong? No errors

Comment: Is the find returning anything, can you show data/

Comment: If nothing happens then your code is not properly assigned to the button.

Comment: set a break point on the with statement and when it stops there use F8 to go through step by step to debug your code and see whats happening.

Comment: Is your row 2 on `Sheets("Coverage Data").` have the column labels.  Maybe you need to change it to row 1 `For Each R In Sheets("Coverage Data").Range("A1:AD1")` and use offset on the paste `R.Offset(1)`

Comment: When you say "when pressing run", you mean the green "play" button in the IDE's toolbar? If so then hit F9 to place a breakpoint on the `With` statement, *then* F5 to "run" it. We can't debug and step through your code for you. As it stands your question is too vague to be answerable. That said `If Len(Msg)` reads like an ugly hack.

Comment: Is `vllf ` intended to be `vbLF` ?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the button and click 'Assign Macro'.  Select the Macro that you want to fire when the button is clicked.  Then just hit OK.  That's it.